# ID番号または名前を探索鍵として二分探索で調べて結果を表示するプログラム

Tags: c

データ数を読み込み、そのデーター分だけIDと名前を入力させ、IDで昇順にするか、または名前でアルファベット順にするかを入力させ、その結果を出力するプログラムを作成したいのですが、入力の仕方によって結果がおかしくなってしまいます。

というのも、先に実行結果を示してしまいますが、例えば以下のような時は

```
$ ./a.out
データ数: 3
a[0]
  ID  :  1
  名前: suzuki
a[1]
  ID  : 2
  名前: kato
a[2]
  ID  : 3
  名前: sano
1) ID, 2) 名前: 2

要素  ID  名前
a[0]:  2  kato           
a[1]:  3  sano           
a[2]:  1  suzuki         
探索鍵(名前): sano
探索鍵(名前) sano, ID 3 が a[1] に見つかりました
```

このように名前もアルファベット順になり、それが存在するIDも表示しますが、
以下のようなとき、

```
$ ./a.out
データ数: 3
a[0]
  ID  : 2
  名前: kato
a[1]
  ID  : 1
  名前: sano
a[2]
  ID  : 4
  名前: suzuki
1) ID, 2) 名前: 2

要素  ID  名前
a[0]:  2  kato           
a[1]:  1  sano           
a[2]:  4  suzuki         
探索鍵(名前): suzuki
探索鍵(名前) �U は見つかりませんでした
```

実行結果が変になってしまいます。

自分は以下のようにプログラムを作成したのですが、どこがおかしいのかがわからなかったので
よろしくお願いします。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct student{
    int id;
    char name[20];
};
typedef struct student Student;

/* 二つのポインタ引数で示される Student型の値を入れかえる */
void swap_student( struct student *a,struct student *b )
{
    struct student t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}

/* 長さ size のStudent型配列 a[] の各要素を
   選択ソートでid順（昇順）に並べかえる */
void ssort_id( Student a[],int n )
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=n-1;i>=1;i--){
     for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(a[j].id>a[j+1].id){
             swap_student(&a[j],&a[j+1]);
        }
      }
    }
}

/* 長さ size のStudent型配列 a[] の各要素を
   選択ソートで名前順（昇順）に並べかえる */
void ssort_name( Student a[],int size )
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
     for(j=size-1;j>i;j--){
      if(strcmp(a[j-1].name,a[j].name)>0){
       swap_student(&a[j-1],&a[j]);
      }
    }
  } 
}

/* 配列 a[] のメンバ id に探索鍵(ID) x があるかどうかを二分探索で判定する */
int bsearch_id( Student a[],int p,int q,int x )
{
    int t=(p+q)/2;
    if(p>q){
      return -1;
    }
    if(a[t].id==x){
      return t;
    }
    if(a[t].id>x){
      q=t-1;
    } else{
      p=q+1;
    }
    return bsearch_id(a,p,q,x);
}

/* 配列 a[] のメンバ name に探索鍵(名前) x があるかどうかを二分探索で判定する */
int bsearch_name( Student a[],int p,int q,char x[] )
{
    int t=(p+q)/2;
    if(p>q){
      return -1;
    }
    if (!strcmp(a[t].name,x)){
      return t;
    }
    if(strcmp(a[t].name,x)>0){
      q=t-1;
    } else{
      p=q+1;
    }
    return bsearch_name(a,p,q,x);
}

/* 長さ size の配列 a[] の各要素にユーザからの入力値を格納する */
void get_students(Student a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("a[%d]\n", i);
        printf("  ID  : ");  scanf("%d", &a[i].id );
        printf("  名前: ");  scanf("%s", a[i].name );
    }
}

/* 長さ size の配列 a[] を表示する */
void put_students(Student a[], int size)
{
    int i;

    printf("\n要素  ID  名前\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("a[%d]: %2d  %-15s\n", i, a[i].id, a[i].name);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int size,horw,pos,key;
    char keystr[20];
    Student a[MAX_SIZE];

    printf("データ数: ");  scanf("%d", &size);
    get_students(a, size);
    printf("1) ID, 2) 名前: ");
    scanf("%d", &horw);

    switch (horw) {
    case 1:
        ssort_id( a,size ); /* ID番号で昇順に並べ替え */
        put_students(a, size);
        printf("探索鍵(ID): ");  scanf("%d", &key);
        pos = bsearch_id(a,0,size-1,key);
        if (pos >= 0) {
            printf("探索鍵(ID) %d, 名前 %s が a[%d] に見つかりました\n", key,a[pos].name,pos );
        } else {
            printf("探索鍵(ID) %d は見つかりませんでした\n", key );
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        ssort_name(a,size); /* 名前で昇順に並べ替え */
        put_students(a, size);
        printf("探索鍵(名前): ");  scanf("%s", keystr);
        pos = bsearch_name(a,0,size-1,keystr);
        if (pos >= 0) {
            printf("探索鍵(名前) %s, ID %d が a[%d] に見つかりました\n", keystr,a[pos].id,pos );
        } else {
            printf("探索鍵(名前) %s は見つかりませんでした\n", a[pos].name );
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: まぁ、`p=q+1;` ではないですよね。

Answer (score 0):

これなら、動くかもです。
未検証ですが

```
int bsearch_name( Student a[],int p,int q,char x[] )
{
    int t=(p+q)/2;
    if(p>q){
      return -1;
    }
    if (!strcmp(a[t].name,x)){
      return t;
    }
    if(strcmp(a[t].name,x)>0){
      q=t;
    } else{
      p=t;
    }
    return bsearch_name(a,p,q,x);
}
```